# Laravel: how to prevent multiple login with the same user account?

Tags: php, laravel

How to prevent multiple login with same user credentials in any kind of browser? thank you...

Answer (score 5):

you can use  `auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);` function

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

it will logout all other user with same user

***in `LoginController.php`***
add this code

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }
        auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

in above code overwrite same code which laravel use internally

only `auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);` is added as u need this feature

and u need to  un-commented in your app/Http/Kernel.php class' web middleware group:

```php
'web' => [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    // ...
],
```

Comment: thank you...so much ... maraming salamat po,,,

Comment: where can i add this function?